# How To Display Tooltip for TextBox While Entering the Text in that in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins

I have searched a lot on google. But i am not able to find the right answer for how to display the tooltip when **focus** in a **textbox**.

i have found **qtip** plugin but it works only for mouseover and mouseout.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of JQuery plugins to use for this requirement. Check this [JQuery tooltip plugin demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/) for examples